# Having trouble connecting Unity3d WebGL project build to database, works fine in editor

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I used this code to connect my Unity project to my MySql database:

```
public void SetupSQLConnection()
{
    Debug.Log("Connection Function Started");
    if (connection == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("If connection == null");
        try
        {
            Debug.Log("Try block started");
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            connBuilder.Server = "localhost";
            connBuilder.UserID = "root";
            connBuilder.Database = "therapygame";
            connBuilder.Password = "";
            connBuilder.OldGuids = true;

            Debug.Log("String set");
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString);
            Debug.Log("new MySqlConnection");
            connection.Open();
            Debug.Log("connection");
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError("MySQL Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when running my project in the Unity3d editor. However, when I build the WebGL, it no longer connects to the database.

The error happens between the Debug.Logs of "new MySqlConnection" and "connection". In other words, it is failing at the connection.Open(); statement.

Here is the console log in Google Chrome:

```
SystemException: Thread creation failed.

Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Threading.Timer.Scheduler' threw an exception.

Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Threading.Timer' threw an exception.

Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager' threw an exception.


(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

And here is the source of that error (it is so large that I had to break it apart into sections)(see following section to know what to look for):

https://0bin.net/paste/-28c3BvLx+Nx+Q+L#ltyOWWb+IembwSAgNKzPCRwvI5MkPOrUfgOAs3i4R+f

https://0bin.net/paste/ZleyLDeOcgr3kj-e#OPVr3oIC8-mcO9mXB1pV/+ONcdnUB+3I1RCy37/NI+p

https://0bin.net/paste/+rbHWsKmXhIXM50A#PaAFLCeDJZzIQTWczYbDepmubFhSaeDWqzcB+ItUTnb

https://0bin.net/paste/VdNv2NA8K0--ZXNM#fomzOVZ9iNOJDHequiSAbuv6I3lxDXXL+E5WK6GPKZv

https://0bin.net/paste/zcDPoycv5lqbjRcA#h0WNQdMSU4VtdIbwzOByW5csu68FERPvEdOKJz9oUeA

Copy this and paste it into ctrl+f find:

```
function _JS_Log_Dump(ptr, type) {
var str = Pointer_stringify(ptr);
if (typeof dump == "function") dump(str);
switch (type) {
case 0:
case 1:
case 4:
console.error(str);
return;
case 2:
console.warn(str);
return;
case 3:
case 5:
console.log(str);
return;
default:
console.error("Unknown console message type!");
console.error(str);
}
}
```

the lines that are in question are

```
case 4:
console.error(str);
```

I have included System.Data.dll and MySql.Data.dll to my Visual Studio references, and also all the I18N files. I have also put those files in my built project file path.

Please tell me if you need additional information, I tried to include everything I thought was relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since WebGL builds boil down to javascript, you cannot use standard C# networking APIs in those builds (MySQL connector uses ADO.NET and is therefore, unfortunately, disqualified from WebGL builds).  There is some good information on [Networking with Unity WebGL Builds](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html) but here's the part relevant to your situation:

> Due to security implications, JavaScript code does not have direct
>   access to IP Sockets to implement network connectivity. As a result,
>   the .NET networking  classes (ie, everything in the System.Net
>   namespace, particularly System.Net.Sockets) are non-functional in
>   WebGL . The same applies to Unity’s old UnityEngine.Network* classes,
>   which are not available when building for WebGL.
>
> If you need to use Networking in WebGL, you currently have the options
>   to use the WWW or UnityWebRequest classes in Unity or the new Unity
>   Networking features which support WebGL, or to implement your own
>   networking using WebSockets or WebRTC in JavaScript.

Keep in mind the "new Unity Networking features" it mentions are part of UNet, [which is being deprecated](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001252086-UNet-Deprecation-FAQ).  EDIT: It looks like the entire [NetworkTransport API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkTransport.html) is gone.

---

Hopefully you can find a solution while digging through those articles. I haven't tried anything with UNet, WebSockets, or WebRTC but personally, to solve this issue in my own WebGL projects, I use `UnityWebRequest` to send `POST` requests to a server I'm hosting on AWS that's running a LAMP stack.  My php pages process the requests and the MySQL database is sitting there on the same server.

Comment: They did very recently announce that UNet is being kept alive till 2019.LTS